# What would be the most efficient way to use python modules?

Tags: python, python-module

I am learning to use python and I need to use three specific modules repeatedly. I don't want to keep importing them over and over again whenever I am working on a new script. So I was wondering how I could point python to always use those modules at startup?

Thanks!

Comment: " I don't want to keep importing them over and over again whenever I am working on a new script." Why not? That's normally how it is done. It is good to clearly and explicitly perform your imports.

Comment: From [the zen of python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), “Explicit is better than implicit.”

Comment: You will read your code many more times than you write it, so a little more typing is a small price to pay for greater clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with everyone else here re: explicitness, but I'm going to note a corner case you might see in the wild. I would not structure your code this way, but I've seen it.

---

If you structure your code as:

```
+ mypackage/
 +  my_math.py
 +  foo.py
```

my_math.py:

```
import math
```

foo.py:

```
from my_math import *
if math.sin(0) == 0:
    print("foo.py imported math from my_math! It was very effective!")
```

Then foo will not raise a NameError when run.

---

The reason I mention this is that you might see the following in some repos:

```
+ mypackage/
+   __init__.py
+   foo.py
```

**__init__.py:**

```
import math
```

**foo.py:**

```
from mypackage import *
if math.sin(0) == 0:
    print("foo.py import math from mypackage implicitly, via __init__.py")
```

Then if foo.py is run, it will not error. 
Again, do follow the majority advice here. Just import in each file. The above is just a sidenote.